# Cannot get log4j log file created

Tags: java, jar, log4j

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the answers have worked for me.  I have the following `log4j.properties` file:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE, stdout

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/home/sutureself/log.out
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

# Define the layout for the stdout appender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}
```

I have this file located in `<workspace-root>/resources` (I have tried it within `src` and in `<workspace-root>`.  The `resources` folder has been added to the build path in Eclipse, along with the jar files `log4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar` and `log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar`.  However, when I export the project as a runnable jar, no log file is created, and also nothing is written to stdout either.

I read in some of the other answers on SO, that it needs to be in a folder that is on your classpath.  So I added the following to my code:

```
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
System.out.println("Classpath [" + classpath + "]");
```

... and put the properties file in the location this printed out, but still no file or stdout.  In each of my java files where the logger is used, it is implemented:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class SutureSelfExample {
    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(SutureSelfExample.class.getName());

    ...

    log.info("Log something interesting.");
}
```

If I run the jar with the following commands:

```
./SutureSelfRunnable.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=./log4j.properties
./SutureSelfRunnable.jar -cp /home/sutureself/
```

... still nothing.

What is missing?  Do I need to have more in my Java code in order to get this working?

Comment: Put the `log4j.properties` (and the jars) in `/home/sutureself/`; if that is your desired CLASSPATH. I would recommend `/home/sutureself/jars` myself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for `log4j 2`  you need to config by xml config file : see [Configuration Log4j 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) for more.

if you want to use the properties file you must downgrade your libs to `log4j 1.x`.

Comment: That seems to be my problem.  Thanks for this.  This SO answer helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206993/very-simple-log4j2-xml-configuration-file-using-console-and-file-appender